# What's a good mongodb shard key for this Schema?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Schema

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5069d68700a2934015000000"),
        "port_name" : "CL1-A",
        "metric" : 340,
        "port_number" : "0",
        "datetime" : ISODate("2012-09-30T13:44:00Z"),
        "array_serial" : "12345"
}
```

Each array has 128 ports, and each document is one minute of data for that metric. It would seem that the array_serial is not a good choice for a shard key because of the low cardinality, that is, all the data for serial `12345` would have to remain on the same shard and not be split into chunks, correct?

It would seem that `port_number` would allow for moderate cardinality, however it would fail the query isolation, as a single query of multiple ports on the same array would span multiple shards. I don't anticipate users need to query for more than 4-8 ports at a time.

Is the answer a combination? Should I use a piece of the datetime, like month, or week?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding array serial, yes that is correct.

If you go for "port_number", it'll have high enough cardinality and will mean that all documents with the same "port_number" will reside in the same chunk but if a query arrives for a range of ports, then it'll hit multiple shards.

As you've guessed, choosing the correct shard key is very important and hard. A "perfect" shard key  satisfies three mutually exclusive goals:

- Writes should be distributed evenly over the shards
- Queries of individual documents should be distributed evenly over the shards
- Range queries and sorts should be efficient, which means that elements in a sequence should all be on the **same** shard.

One of the reasons to avoid a sequential shard key is that it will create hotspots on inserts: at any given time a single shard will be taking all the insert load (it's good for query isolation but not for performance ultimately - hence _id and "datetime" aren't good choices). I would possibly go for a  compound shard key. There are some good discussions on the Google Group on this topic:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/yolfc6B3JL8

If you choose something like { array_serial : 1 , datetime : 1 } then the data for "array_serial" will be broken into many chunks (based on the datetime) if needed and spread across servers. Use the full "datatime" value.

How is the "array_serial" decided? What are the range of values? I'm presuming port_name changes as port_number changes?

Given what you've said, I would probably go for { port_number : 1, datetime: 1}, it's not perfect but it's not bad.

Is it the best choice for you? It really depends on usage information.

- What are your most common queries?

If you're mostly going to be doing queries for a particular name within a particular port number range then this might be the best key for you.

If, on the other hand, you will mostly be performing queries of all 'names' based on datetime and regardless of port number then you'll be doing a scatter/gather query every time, which will reduce the overall performance of your cluster.

Additionally,ask yourself

- Can a single shard handle all of your inserts?
- Is range query performance really important for you?

Based on your question, I'm guessing that you've already read the link on [choosing a shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-internals/#sharding-internals-shard-keys) :)

Here are some further discussions on picking a good shard key that may help you:

- Kristina Chodrow's excellent book "Scaling MongoDB"
- [Kristina's blog post on shard keys](http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2011/01/04/how-to-choose-a-shard-key-the-card-game/)
- [Tyler Brock's overview presentation on sharding](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/sharding-overview)
- [Antoine Girbal's presentation on Sharding Best Practices](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/Sharding-Best-Practices-Advanced)